# filter unique string from paragraph and make it clickable and place to their original position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, react-native

I have a Paragraph. in this para have lot of hashtags strings like #react ,#cool etc.
I have to do that first filter all the hashtags strings from the paragraph and again place their original position with make it clickable.

**Input**

const str = "I am john mike . I love #reactProgramming. I have 2 years of experience in React Native Developer #ReactNative. #JS. I am working on the xyz Ltd. #xyz"

**Output**

I am john mike . I love `#reactProgramming`. I have 2 years of experience in React Native Developer `#ReactNative`. `#JS`. I am working on the xyz Ltd. `#xyz`

Now, all the hashtags is clickable and if we click on a specific hashtag. it should be log their own value like #JS.

Code:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
export default function App() {
const str = "I am john mike . I love #reactProgramming. I have 2 years of experience in React Native Developer #ReactNative. #JS. I am working on the xyz Ltd. #xyz"

const [data,setData]=useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  
  });
  const getHashTag = ()=>{
    const regexp = /\B\#\w\w+\b/g
   const  result = str.match(regexp);
    if (result) {
        setData(result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{str}</h1>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive your goal by using `replace` method, but instead of replacing on the original string, you can use `replace` method to generate your `jSX` elements and  pushing  them into an array and then render your array, like this:

```js
const str = "I am john mike . I love #reactProgramming. I have 2 years of experience in React Native Developer #ReactNative. #JS. I am working on the xyz Ltd. #xyz";

function App() {
  const handleClickOnTag = (tag)=>{ alert(tag) }
  const renderTags = (str)=> {
    let result = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;
    const regexp = /\B\#\w\w+\b/g

    str.replace(regexp, (tag,tagIndex)=> {
      result.push(str.slice(lastIndex, tagIndex));
      lastIndex = tagIndex + tag.length;
      result.push(<button key={tag} onClick={()=> handleClickOnTag(tag)}>{tag}</button>)
    })

    return result;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{renderTags(str)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
button{
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ReactJS**

```js
let str= "Hello world, Here is #Clickable #Hashtag";

function App() {
  const clickableHashtagGenerator = ( str, baseUrl ) => {

  let elem = str;
      elem = elem.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='link' href="$1" target='_blank'>$1</a>`)
        .replace(/(@[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='username' title='$1'>$1</a>`)
        .replace(/(#[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='hashtag' >$1</a>`)
        
        return elem

   }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
      Note: Use HTML parser to display as HTML content
      { clickableHashtagGenerator( str ) }</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
const clickableHashtagGenerator = ( contentElement, baseUrl ) => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(contentElement);
      elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML
        .replace(/(#[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='hashtag' href='${baseUrl}/$1'>$1</a>`)

  return elem
}

clickableHashtagGenerator( '#myContent', 'http://www.exmple.com');
```

```css
#myContent { font-size: 24px; }

.hashtag { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="myContent">Hello world, Here is #Clickable #Hashtag.</div>
```